# How to remove the last string from a stringbuilder?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I'm dynamically creating a string

```
StringBuilder preparedStatement = new StringBuilder();
states.keySet().forEach(key -> preparedStatement
               .append(key)
               .append(" = ")
               .append(":")
               .append(key)
               .append(" AND "));
```

I want to remove the last `AND` at the end of the loop. Is this possible?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a StringBuilder to keep track of the different fragments added. If you need that just store strings in a list or stack and combine them as required yourself.

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to only add the `AND` when you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You know how wide the `" AND "` is, so just use [`StringBuilder#delete`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete-int-int-):

```java
preparedStatement.delete(preparedStatement.length() - " AND ".length(),
                         preparedStatement.length()
                        );
```

Or, if you're about to turn it into a `String` anyway, use [`StringBuilder#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring-int-int-):

```java
String result = preparedStatement.substring(0,
                                            preparedStatement.length()
                                                - " AND ".length()
                                           );
```

Comment: Could do `preparedStatement.setLength(preparedStatement.length() - " AND ".length())` to avoid the excessive `System.arraycopy` performed by `delete` & avoid the excess `String` created by `substring`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think that `StringBuilder` does not support deleting in general case. It was designed to build a string.

I reccomend you just not to add **" AND "** to the builder:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

if(someCheck)
    buf.add(" AND ");
```

This is the best choice, because to delete this part, you have to do a string copy.